# Spring integration for sftp

Tags: spring, sftp, spring-integration

How can I move file from local system to remote FTP using SFTP adapter. I am going through the examples and all are mentioning to copy files from remote FTP to local machine.

I need to move files from local machine to remote system folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp-    2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file-2.2.xsd">

<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
<property name="host" value="localhost"/>
<property name="user" value="user01"/>
<property name="password" value="abc123"/>
<property name="port" value="990"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="sftpChannel"/>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="#{T(System).getProperty('java.io.tmpdir')}" id="fileInbound"
                          channel="sftpChannel" filename-pattern="*.xml">
<int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="100"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                               channel="sftpChannel" charset="UTF-8" remote-directory="/"
                               remote-file-separator="/"/>

</beans>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="moveProcessedFile"
    channel="sftpChannel"
    directory="file:#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('acal.jde.publish.folder')}/processed"
    delete-source-files="true" order="2" />
```

I tried this but not able to move file to processed folder.

Comment: You need only `outbound-channel-adapter` to put file to SFTP. What do you use to put your payload to `inputChannel`?

Comment: BTW, you can actually see example that puts file on a remote dir via SFTP [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/sftp/SftpOutboundTransferSample.java)

Comment: @Dmitry So I need to define only outbound-channel adapter? if so How can I configure local folder where it needs to pick the file?

Comment: You don't specify this in `outbound-channel-adapter`, you only specify input channel. And how you put data in this channel is up to you: you can, for example, create a chain that will read local directory and write payload to `inputChannel`, or you can read file and put it as a payload manually in a corn job, and many other options, you should decide which one suits you best. In the link I gave you above `MessageChannel.send` is called explicitly and channel instance is obtained from app context - that's an option as well.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for the inputs.I added the channel and read the files and then called outbound-channel-adapter.edit configurations above but still files are not moving. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Why do you have `sftpSessionFactory` as a `channel` in `inbound-channel-adapter`? It should define the message channel to which the payload shall be forwarded to, so in your case it seems like it should be `publishToSFTPChannel`. And why use `publish-subscribe-channel`? Simple point-to-point channel should suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's configuration based on yours that I actually checked to be working, you can use it as a starting point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
   xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file-2.2.xsd">

<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="user" value="user01"/>
    <property name="password" value="abc123"/>
    <property name="port" value="990"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="sftpChannel"/>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="#{T(System).getProperty('java.io.tmpdir')}" id="fileInbound"
                              channel="sftpChannel" filename-pattern="*.xml">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="100"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                                   channel="sftpChannel" charset="UTF-8" remote-directory="/"
                                   remote-file-separator="/"/>

</beans>
```

Problems with your configuration:

1. You use `sftpSessionFactory` as a channel in `inbound-channel-adapter`. It should define the message channel to which the payload shall be forwarded to, so in your case it seems like it should be `publishToSFTPChannel`
2. `publish-subscribe-channel` used instead of simple point-to-point channel

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, Then I tried to move the files to processed folder and not able to move the files into folder.Can you have look on my configuration please.

Comment: I think you better create another question each time and not modify the existing one. There are multiple ways you can handle this. `sftpChannel` is direct channel now, so only one consumer can use it. You can, for example, create splitter or router to put you message to different channels for each adapter. Also, `publish-subscribe-channel` may actually be useful for you now - you can read local file, and then it will be sent as a payload to both SFTP and file outbound adapters.

Comment: is int:channel id="sftpChannel" something default or is it like i could have int:channel id="_rd"